# CPU burst balance value for Heroku pg:diagnose

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I've been working to optimize performance of a Postgres database (Standard-0 plan) hosted on Heroku.

When running `heroku pg:diagnose`, I see a `YELLOW: CPU Burst` message, along with a `Balance` value. The `Balance` values I've seen have ranged from ~3 to ~300 over time.

What does the balance value refer to, and how should it be interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry so much about the number itself, though I suspect that it represents the number of CPU burst credits (an AWS concept) remaining. In the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#check-cpu-burst) for pg:diagnose, `YELLOW` sounds like you're actively using burst credits and will run out at some point whereas `RED` indicates that you've exhausted those credits.

Comment: Exactly right - I just heard back from Heroku support, who said "The balance refers to the AWS credits available for plans with burstable CPU. The higher the balance numbers; the more burstable CPU credits you have. The lower the number the closer you are to running out of credits. Once all credits are used up the database will become throttled if it continues on with the same amount of CPU usage. If the CPU usage lowers, the credits start to build up again."